# ListView Rows Invisible On Galaxy S3

Tags: listview, galaxy, invisible

I have a weird ListView display issue on hand.  My application displays a list of status icons and store addresses.  Each row of the list contains an image view and a text view. The ListView display can be changed by selecting a different date. The dates are selected by a radio button group above the ListView. They are yesterday, today and tomorrow.

The ListView display works fine in an emulator targeting at Google API Level 17 for the skin WQVGA400.  However, it displays only blank rows on the Galaxy S3 phone for yesterday and today. The row's icon and text are there as I can verify by clicking on a row and see the content in a popup. The ListView works fine for tomorrow's data all the time on Galaxy S3. My app's manifest file specifies android:minSdkVersion="14" and android:targetSdkVersion="17". My ListView is filled with a custom adapter.

I did lots of research on the internet but can not find an answer.  I suspect it's related to a memory issue. Can anyone help answer how to fix this defect?  Thanks in advance.

Here's some relevant code.  Hope they provide enough info.

1. The frgment XML containing the ListView:

   ```
   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/radioVisitDate"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       ...

   </RadioGroup>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:background="#1BD6E0">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/visit_status_header"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:foreground="#000000"
           android:text="@string/visit_status"
       />

       ...

   </LinearLayout>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@android:id/list" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
   ```
2. The Fragment's code file:

...

```
public class PugsMobileStoreStopsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    public interface OnFragmentEventsListener 
    {
        public void onCursorLoadStatus(Intent loadStatusIntent);
        public void onGetStoreStopsServiceStart(Intent startGetStoreStopsServiceIntent);
        public void OnUserSettingsErrorListener(Intent correctUserSettingsIntent);
    }

    private OnFragmentEventsListener fragmentEventListener;
    private Intent loadStatusIntent = null;
    private Intent getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent = null;
    private Intent getOrderLineItemsIntent = null;
    private Intent correctUserSettingsIntent = null;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo> storeStopInfos = null;
    private PugsMobileStoreStopsAdapter storeStopInfosAdapter;
    private ListView storeStopsListView = null;
    private Calendar visitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    private boolean tomorrowSeleted = false;
    private SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
    private int salesRepNumber = 0;
    private boolean salesRepNumEmptyAlertDisplayed = false;
    private boolean salesRepNumNonNumericAlertDisplayed = false;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;
    private int selectedBtnId = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pugs_mobile_store_stops_fragment, null); 
        storeStopsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        storeStopsListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        storeStopInfos = new SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo>();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_STORE_VISIT.ordinal(), null, this);  
        RadioGroup daySelectionRadiogroup = (RadioGroup)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioVisitDate);
        restoreVisitDateSelection();

        daySelectionRadiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int radioButtonId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                switch(radioButtonId) 
                {
                    case R.id.radioYesterday:
                        tomorrowSeleted = false;
                        visitDate = PugsMobileUtilities.getYesterday();
                        resetStoreStopListView();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioToday:
                         tomorrowSeleted = false;
                         visitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                         resetStoreStopListView();
                         break;
                    case R.id.radioTomorrow: 
                        tomorrowSeleted = true;
                        visitDate= PugsMobileUtilities.getTomorrow();
                        resetStoreStopListView();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }              
            }
        });

        Thread t = 
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            updateStoreStops(); 
                        }
                     });
        t.start();
    }

    private void restoreVisitDateSelection()
    {   
        if (selectedBtnId > 0)
        {
            ((RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(selectedBtnId)).setSelected(true);
        }
    }

    private void resetStoreStopListView()
    {
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
               public void run() 
               {
                   storeStopsListView.setAdapter(null);

                   getLoaderManager().restartLoader(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_STORE_VISIT.ordinal(), null, PugsMobileStoreStopsFragment.this);
               }
             });
    }

    public void saveFragmentVariaqbles()
    {
        sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGS_MOBILE_SHARED_PREF, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (null != sharedPref)
        {
            RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioVisitDate); 
            selectedBtnId = g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.SELECTED_VISIT_DATE_RADIO_BUTTON, selectedBtnId);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    ...

    public void updateStoreStops() 
    {   
        boolean bRemovePreviousSalesRepData = false;
        Integer salesRepNumber = getSalesRepNumber();
        int prevSalesRepNumber = getPreviousSalesRepNumber();

        if (salesRepNumber == PugsMobileConstansDefinition.EMPTY_TEXT_ERR_CODE || salesRepNumber == PugsMobileConstansDefinition.NON_NUMERIC_TEXT_ERR_CODE )
        {
            return;
        }

        if (prevSalesRepNumber == salesRepNumber.intValue())
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_STORE_VISIT.ordinal(), null, PugsMobileStoreStopsFragment.this);  
                }
            }); 
        }
        else
        {
            prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString(UserSettingsActivity.SETTINGS_PREVIOUS_ROUTE_NUMBER,salesRepNumber.toString());
            prefsEditor.commit();

            if (prevSalesRepNumber > 0)
            {
                bRemovePreviousSalesRepData = true;
            }

            startDataService(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_STORE_VISIT.ordinal(), bRemovePreviousSalesRepData);
        }
    }

    public void updateStoreVisitListView()
    {
        requestStoreStopsInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try 
        {
            fragmentEventListener = (OnFragmentEventsListener) activity;
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException e) 
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentEventsListener");
        }

    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
    {
        CursorLoader loader = null;

        if (IsSalesRepNumberValid())
        {
            ...
        }           
        return loader;
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        retrieveDataFromCursor(cursor,loader.getId());
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
    {
        switch(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.dataRequesterEnums[loader.getId()])
        {
            case ENUM_STORE_VISIT: storeStopsListView.setAdapter(null);
              break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private CursorLoader getStoreStopsLoader()
    {   
        ...
        return loader;
    }

    private CursorLoader getRefreshStoreStopsLoader()
    {   
        ...
        return loader;
    }

    private void processStoreStopsData(Cursor cursor)
    {
        int count = 0;

        try
        {
            if (null != cursor)
            {
                String storeAddress = null;
                int visitStatus = 0;
                int rowIndex = -1;
                PugsMobileStoreStopInfo storeStopInfo = null;
                count = cursor.getCount();

                if (0 == count)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (null != storeStopInfos)
                {
                    storeStopInfos.clear();
                    storeStopInfos = null;
                }

                storeStopInfos = new SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo>();
                PugsMobileAlarmReceiver.geoDataList.clear();

                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    rowIndex = cursor.getPosition();

                    storeStopInfo = new PugsMobileStoreStopInfo();
                    storeStopInfo.setStoreName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_NAME)));

                    storeAddress += " ";
                    storeAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS));
                    storeAddress += ", " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_CITY));
                    storeAddress += ", " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_STATE));

                    storeStopInfo.setStoreAddress(storeAddress);

                    visitStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_VISIT_STATUS));

                    if (tomorrowSeleted)
                    {
                        visitStatus = 3;
                    }

                    storeStopInfo.setStoreVisitStatus(visitStatus);         
                    storeStopInfo.setStoreId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_ID)));
                    storeStopInfo.setListHeaderId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_LISTHEADER_ID)));
                    storeStopInfo.setBillId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_BILL_ID)));

                    PugsGeoDataInfo storeGeoInfo = new PugsGeoDataInfo();
                    storeGeoInfo.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_LATITUDE))));
                    storeGeoInfo.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_LONGITUDE))));
                    PugsMobileAlarmReceiver.geoDataList.add(storeGeoInfo);//Save store geo data 

                    storeStopInfos.append(rowIndex, storeStopInfo);
                }

                if (null != storeStopInfos.get(0))
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){public void run() {populateStoreStopsList(storeStopInfos);}});
                }
                else
                {
                    updateStoreStops();
                }
            }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void retrieveDataFromCursor(Cursor cursor, int dataRequesterID)
    {
        loadStatusIntent = null;
        loadStatusIntent = new Intent();
        loadStatusIntent.setAction(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.LOAD_FINISHED);
        fragmentEventListener.onCursorLoadStatus(loadStatusIntent);

        switch(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.dataRequesterEnums[dataRequesterID])
        {   
            case ENUM_STORE_VISIT:
                 processStoreStopsData(cursor);
              break;
            case ENUM_REFRESH_STORE_VISIT:  
                 processStoreStopsData(cursor);     
              break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void populateStoreStopsList(SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo> storeStops)
    {
        //Initialize the adapter sending the current context
        storeStopInfosAdapter = new PugsMobileStoreStopsAdapter(getActivity(), storeStops);
        storeStopInfosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        storeStopsListView.setAdapter(storeStopInfosAdapter); 
    }

    private void startDataService(int dataType, boolean bRemovePreviousSalesRepData)
    {
        Intent dataIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PugsMobileDataService.class);

        ...
        getActivity().startService(dataIntent); 
    }

    /* @param variableName - name of drawable, e.g R.drawable.<b>image</b>
     * @param Ã‘ï¿½ - class of resource, e.g R.drawable, of R.raw
     * @return integer id of resource
    */
    public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c)
    {
        Field field = null;
        int resId = 0;

        try 
        {               
            field = c.getField(variableName);

            try 
            {
                resId = field.getInt(null);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return resId;
     }

    public int getSalesRepNumber()
    {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String strSalesRepNum = prefs.getString(UserSettingsActivity.SETTINGS_ROUTE_NUMBER, "none");
        strSalesRepNum.trim();

        if (strSalesRepNum.equalsIgnoreCase("none"))
        {       
            return PugsMobileConstansDefinition.EMPTY_TEXT_ERR_CODE;
        }
        else if (!isNumeric(strSalesRepNum))
        {
            //salesRepNumEmptyAlertDisplayed = false;   
            salesRepNumNonNumericAlertDisplayed = false;
            return PugsMobileConstansDefinition.NON_NUMERIC_TEXT_ERR_CODE;
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(strSalesRepNum);

    }

    public int getPreviousSalesRepNumber()
    {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String strSalesRepNum = prefs.getString(UserSettingsActivity.SETTINGS_PREVIOUS_ROUTE_NUMBER, "none");
        strSalesRepNum.trim();

        if (strSalesRepNum.equalsIgnoreCase("none"))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(strSalesRepNum);
    }

    public boolean isNumeric(String s) 
    {  
        return s.matches("\\d+");  
    } 

    public void requestStoreStopsInfo()
    {
        getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent = null;
        getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent = new Intent();
        getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent.setAction(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGS_MOBILE_MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION);
        getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGS_MOBILE_MESSAGE_EXTRA, PugsMobileConstansDefinition.STORE_STOPS_SERVICE_STARTED);
        fragmentEventListener.onGetStoreStopsServiceStart(getStoreStopsServiceStatusIntent);

        //If SQLite db is empty, then get data from SQL server
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                                 
                startDataService(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_STORE_VISIT.ordinal(), false);
            }
        });

        t.start();  
    }

    public void requestLineItemsInfo()
    {
        getOrderLineItemsIntent = null;
        getOrderLineItemsIntent = new Intent();
        getOrderLineItemsIntent.setAction(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGS_MOBILE_MESSAGE_SENT_ACTION);
        getOrderLineItemsIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGS_MOBILE_MESSAGE_EXTRA, PugsMobileConstansDefinition.ORDER_LINE_ITEMS_SERVICE_STARTED);
        fragmentEventListener.onGetStoreStopsServiceStart(getOrderLineItemsIntent);

        //If SQLite db is empty, then get data from SQL server
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                                 
                startDataService(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.DataRequester.ENUM_ORDER_LINE_ITEMS.ordinal(), false);
            }
        });

        t.start();  
    }

    private boolean IsSalesRepNumberValid()
    {
        boolean bValid = true;  

        salesRepNumber = getSalesRepNumber();
        correctUserSettingsIntent = null;
        correctUserSettingsIntent = new Intent();
        correctUserSettingsIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.SALESREP_NUMBER_EMPTY, false);
        correctUserSettingsIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.SALESREP_NUMERIC_ID_NEEDED, false);

        if (PugsMobileConstansDefinition.EMPTY_TEXT_ERR_CODE == salesRepNumber)
        {
            if (!salesRepNumEmptyAlertDisplayed)
            {           
                correctUserSettingsIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.SALESREP_NUMBER_EMPTY, true);
                fragmentEventListener.OnUserSettingsErrorListener(correctUserSettingsIntent);
                salesRepNumEmptyAlertDisplayed = true;      
            }   
            bValid = false; 
        }
        else if (PugsMobileConstansDefinition.NON_NUMERIC_TEXT_ERR_CODE == salesRepNumber)
        {
            if (!salesRepNumNonNumericAlertDisplayed)
            {
                correctUserSettingsIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.SALESREP_NUMERIC_ID_NEEDED, true);
                fragmentEventListener.OnUserSettingsErrorListener(correctUserSettingsIntent);
                salesRepNumNonNumericAlertDisplayed = true;
            }   
            bValid = false; 
        }

        return bValid;
    }   
}
```

1. The custom adapter code to fill the list view

....

```
public class PugsMobileStoreStopsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener 
{
    private SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo> storeStops = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewHolder holder = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public PugsMobileStoreStopsAdapter(Context context, SparseArray<PugsMobileStoreStopInfo> storeStopInfos) 
    {
        if (null != storeStops)
        {
            storeStops.clear();
            storeStops = null;
        }

        this.storeStops = storeStopInfos;
        this.context = context; 
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);   
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {     
        return storeStops.size();    
    }


    public PugsMobileStoreStopInfo getItem(int position)
    {
        return storeStops.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null) 
        { 
            holder = null;
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            mInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pugsmobile_store_stop_row_layout, parent,false);

            holder.storeVisitStatus   = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeVisitStatus);
            holder.storeNameAddress   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeNameAddress);
            holder.storeId            = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeId);
            holder.listHeaderId       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listHeaderId);
            holder.billId             = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.billId);

            convertView.setTag(holder);  
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new onItemClickListener(position));    
        }
        else 
        {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } 

        holder.storeNameAddress.setText(storeStops.get(position).getStoreName() + ", " + storeStops.get(position).getStoreAddress());
        holder.storeId.setText(storeStops.get(position).getStoreId().toString());
        holder.listHeaderId.setText(storeStops.get(position).getListHeaderId().toString());
        holder.billId.setText(storeStops.get(position).getBillId().toString());

        switch(storeStops.get(position).getStoreVisitStatus())
        {
            case 0: 
                holder.storeVisitStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.redicon);
              break;

            case 1:
                holder.storeVisitStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowicon);
                  break;

            case 2:
                holder.storeVisitStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenicon);
                  break;

            case 3:
                holder.storeVisitStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.greyicon);
                  break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.v("TAG", "Row button clicked");
    }

    public static class ViewHolder 
    {
        ImageView storeVisitStatus;
        TextView  storeNameAddress; 
        TextView  storeId;
        TextView  listHeaderId;
        TextView  billId;
    }

    private class onItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {       
        private int mPosition;

        onItemClickListener(int position)
        {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            ViewHolder holder =(ViewHolder)arg0.getTag();
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer((String)holder.storeNameAddress.getText(), ",");
            String storeName = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain store name alone

            Intent launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent = new Intent(context, PugsMobileNewOrderActivity.class);
            launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.STORE_NAME, storeName);
            launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGSMOBILE_STORE_ID, Integer.parseInt((String)holder.storeId.getText()));  
            launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGSMOBILE_LIST_HEADER_ID, Integer.parseInt((String)holder.listHeaderId.getText()));
            launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGSMOBILE_BILL_ID, Integer.parseInt((String)holder.billId.getText()));

            context.startActivity(launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent);

            /*
             String[] projection = 
                    new String[] {PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_NAME,
                                  PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_ID
                                 };  
            String where = PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_ID + " = " + storeIdText;

            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();  
            Cursor result = cr.query(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.STORE_VISIT_INFO_CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);

            try
            {
                if (result.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    String storeName = result.getString(result.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_NAME));
                    int storeId = Integer.parseInt(result.getString(result.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PugsMobileStoreVisitInfoTable.COLUMN_STORE_ID)));

                    Intent launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent = 
                            new Intent(context, PugsMobileOrderTypeSelectionActivity.class);
                    launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.STORE_NAME, storeName);
                    launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent.putExtra(PugsMobileConstansDefinition.PUGSMOBILE_STORE_ID, storeId);                 
                    context.startActivity(launchOrderTypeSelectionIntent);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.fillInStackTrace();
            }*/
            //Log.v(TAG, "onItemClick at position" + mPosition);          
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without a code sample. Can you reduce your code down to the simplest program that demonstrates the problem, and share that? (You'll sometimes see this called an SSCCE - a short, self contained, correct example)

Comment: I have posted some of my code and hopefully it will shed some light on the weird defect.

Comment: I found out the cause.  It seems to be related to the smartphone's memory.  In each row of the list view is a color ball icon.  If a red icon is used, then the row becomes blank.  If a yellow or grey icon is used, then the icon and text are visible.  Kind of strange, right?  Anyone knows how to fix it?